# In WebBrowser control get Silverlight Canvas

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, webbrowser-control, writeablebitmap

I have a webbrowser control that loads an html page which contains a silverlight object.

I want to use the webbrowser control to get the silverlight canvas so that I can pass it to a WriteableBitmap() object.

The silverlight is being loaded into a div called SilverlightHostControl and I am trying to get it like this in C#:

```
object element = webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("SilverlightControlHost");
```

This returns a {System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement} which contains the silverlight object but I don't know how to get the Silverlight object so I can use it the WriteableBitmap() object.

Comment: What are you loading into the Silverlight Plugin? XAML or a XAP?

Comment: Xaml generated by javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further research shows that it can't be done.

The primary issue is that the Silverlight is running its own .Net version and the WinForm is running its own .Net version and never the two shall meet.